# Angularjs prevent form submission when input validation fails

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm writing a simple login form using angularjs with some client side input validation to check that the user name and password is not empty and longer than three characters. See the below code:

```
<form name="loginform" novalidate ng-submit="login.submit()" class="css-form">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="control-group input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="login.username" name="username" required ng-minlength="3" placeholder="username" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password" ng-model="login.password" name="password" required ng-minlength="3" placeholder="" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
var controller = function($scope) {

    $scope.login = {
        submit: function() {

            Console.info($scope.login.username + ' ' + $scope.login.password);
        }
    }

};
```

The problem is that the `login.submit` function will be called even if the input is not valid. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

As a side note I can mention that I use bootstrap and requirejs as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516001/angularjs-ng-minlength-validation-is-not-working-form-still-being-submitted

Comment: can we use it without form tag and still form.valid would work on ng-click !

Answer (score 331, accepted):

You can do:

```
<form name="loginform" novalidate ng-submit="loginform.$valid && login.submit()">
```

No need for controller checks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need to check anything in the controller

Comment: I disagree with "no need for controller checks". What if we ant additional validation checks happen in the submit function.

Comment: Perform the additional validation in the directive. Update the validation with $setValidity.

Comment: @b1tsh1ft It would be preferable to have the current state of the validation be always known rather than figured out on submit. That's kinda the whole point of angular's validation. You can't have any visual indication of an invalid state when the scope doesn't know about it.

Comment: @KevinBeal I agree in theory but sometimes need the additional check. My particular case at the time of that comment was on "submit" ran a bunch of custom behavior checks to see if the actions of the user indicated a "bot" (mouse movements, key typing speed, etc.) and would then pop-up additional captcha or flat-out "break" the form at a certain threshold. Best way I found at the time was to run the checks on the actual submit, probably could have been improved on.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but it seems that it evaluates both (i.e. it does not short circuit the boolean after the `&&` I have tried passing in the value as part of the submit and confirmed that the value itself is "false"

Comment: combining the answer with this is Gorgeous. http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/ANxmv/2/

Comment: why we are checking if form is submitted or not with `login.submit()` on `ng-submit` only as i think if we call `ng-submit` function form is submitted obviously.

Answer (score 67):

Change the submit button to:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginform.$invalid">Login</button>
```

Comment: Great answer. You rock!

Comment: You can still submit the form if you press enter while an input field has the focus!

Comment: @Red: See comment above.

Comment: While disabling the button is usually the best way to resolve this, it's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Combining this technique to provide visual feedback for the user together with @Yashua answer to prevent form submission is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

So the suggested answer from TheHippo did not work for me, instead I ended up sending the form as a parameter to the function like so:

```
<form name="loginform" novalidate ng-submit="login.submit(loginForm)" class="css-form">
```

This makes the form available in the controller method:

```
$scope.login = {
    submit : function(form) {
        if(form.$valid)....
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Using your method worked, though.

Comment: This is slightly better than the Accepted Answer because form.$valid check is done in JS and not in HTML.

Comment: However, I don't think you need to pass loginForm to submit function:  I think $scope.loginform should be available in the JS (at least it was for me),  so you could replace form.$valid with $scope.loginform.$valid.

Answer (score 13):

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log in" ng-click="login.onSubmit($event)">
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.login = {
    onSubmit: function(event) {
        if (dataIsntValid) {
            displayErrors();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            submitData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it really necessary to do the check within the onsubmit method? This will mean you have to check that input meets all criteria both in the markup(via angular) and in the js code. In my opinion angular should not call the onsubmit when the input is invalid. see http://www.benlesh.com/2012/11/angular-js-form-validation.html saying "ng-submit cannot be called until the entire form is $valid"

Comment: You could also disable the button to not allow submission if form is valid. You could also use the form an ng-submit. If angular does not handle form validation then `event.preventDefault()` is the way to go, to stop form submission.

Comment: @RunarHalse It is really necessary to do the check.  I agree with you that it should not be this way.  The reason that the onsubmit method is not called in the example that you linked is because that example does not have novalidate set.  The browser is preventing the events from raising, not Angular.  Here is his example w/ nobalidate on: http://plnkr.co/edit/R0C8XA?p=preview.  Notice the form submits.

Comment: perfect just what i was looking for, a way to block form submit using angular

Answer (score 13):

Your forms are automatically put into $scope as an object.  It can be accessed via `$scope[formName]`

Below is an example that will work with your original setup and without having to pass the form itself as a parameter in ng-submit.

```
var controller = function($scope) {

    $scope.login = {
        submit: function() {
            if($scope.loginform.$invalid) return false;

        }
    }

};
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BEWnrP?p=preview

Comment: How would you access the form if you use "As Controller" notation instead of $scope?

Comment: @masimakopoulos: You can simply use `if(this.loginform.$invalid)`.. instead but then in the HTML you have to give the form the name `<form name="ctrl.loginform" ..`. And that's assuming you're using `<div ng-controller="controller as ctrl"..` in your controller-as syntax. Thanks [@JoshCaroll](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html)

Answer (score 4):

Although not a direct solution for the OPs question, if your form is within an `ng-app` context, but you want Angular to ignore it altogether, you can do this explicitly using the [`ngNonBindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive:

```
<form ng-non-bindable>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answers above,

I was having a 2 regular buttons as shown below. (No type="submit"anywhere)

```
<button ng-click="clearAll();" class="btn btn-default">Clear Form</button>
<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="submit();"class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
```

No matter how much i tried, **pressing enter once the form was valid**, the "Clear Form" button was called, clearing the entire form.

As a workaround,

I had to add a dummy submit button which was disabled and hidden. **And This dummy button had to be on top of all the other buttons as shown below**.

```
<button type="submit" ng-hide="true" ng-disabled="true">Dummy</button>

<button ng-click="clearAll();" class="btn btn-default">Clear Form</button>

<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="submit();"class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
```

Well, my intention was never to submit on Enter, so the above given hack just works fine.

Comment: you can stop submit on press enter also by removing the on ng-submit attribute from your form

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I'd also make a contribution. My solution being similar to the post already marked as an answer. Some inline JavaScript checks does the trick.

```
ng-click="form.$invalid ? alert('Please correct the form') : saveTask(task)"
```

Comment: You can still submit the form if you press enter while an input field has the focus!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late and was answered, but I'd like to share the neat stuff I made.
I created an ng-validate directive that hooks the onsubmit of the form, then it issues prevent-default if the $eval is false:

```
app.directive('ngValidate', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (!element.is('form'))
        throw new Error("ng-validate must be set on a form elment!");

    element.bind("submit", function(event) {
        if (!scope.$eval(attrs.ngValidate, {'$event': event}))
            event.preventDefault();
        if (!scope.$$phase)
            scope.$digest();            
    });
  };
});
```

In your html:

```
<form name="offering" method="post" action="offer" ng-validate="<boolean expression">
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, needed to do a normal form post but validate with angularjs first, ng_validate="formName.$valid" worked