# angularjs ng-minlength validation is not working, form still being submitted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I am trying to submit the form on only successful validation. 
validation is working for required but not working for ng-minlength

form input is invalid but form is still being submitted.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" ng-app>
 <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.mobile.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Mobile</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="07XXXXXXXXX" ng-model="mobile" ng-minlength="11"  required />
            <span ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.required" class="help-inline">Required</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.minlength" class="help-inline">Mobile number should be minimum 11 character starting from 07</span>           
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">                       
            <input  class="btn" type="submit" value ="submit" />
        </div>

         count: {{count}}<br />

<tt>myForm.$invalid = {{myForm.$invalid}}</tt><br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pMMke/9/

what am I doing wrong.

I don't want to use submit button disable method.

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails)

Comment: Thanks @maxdec, I am curious why angularjs is not doing which it suppose to do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is what you are doing wrong: you are mixing two concepts, [Angular validators](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input)  and
[HTML5 validators](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp).

The **required** HTML5 validators, for instance, states that:

> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

So, if you try to submit a form that has an input with this attribute, it will show a message explaining this to the user, and it will prevent the form from being sent. This is the behavior you want. Why isn't working for **ng-minlength**? Because **ng-minlength** is an Angular validator (you can tell because it begins with **ng-**), and it doesn't add any special behavior to the form. It simply set the input where it is located to invalid (and hence, the form), and let you decide what to do with it.

You have an option: you can use the **pattern** HTML5 validator, to specify the field requires at least 11 characters. It would like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{11,}">
```

So when you submit a form containing this input, it will no be sent if the user has enter less than 11 characters.

But since we are it, and you are already using the **pattern** validator, you could use the regular expression in its full potential, and define something like:

```
<input type="text" pattern="07[0-9]{9}" />
```

Which will only admit values of 11 characters, that start by "07" and that contains only digits. I have modified your fiddle to show you how it would work: http://jsfiddle.net/helara/w35SQ/

Comment: In my case, it was not working because I was using `textarea` instead of `input`

Comment: Helpful Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I mistakenly used `ngMaxlength="12" ngMinlength="6"` instead of `ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12"`, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Both `ng-minlength` & `mg-maxlength` works in AngularJS.
I've tested this in AngularJS version 1.3.
Make sure to use `novalidate` with `<form>` to disable browser's native validation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @jgritty I believe this **does** provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

### To enter mobile number

```
ng-show="myForm.mobile.$touched && myForm.mobile.$error.required"
```

### For minimum length

```
ng-show="myForm.mobile.$touched && myForm.mobile.$error.minlength"
```

### For maximum length

```
ng-show="myForm.mobile.$touched && myForm.mobile.$error.maxlength"
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me guys

```
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input ng-minlength="11" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" ng-model="avaliacao.cpf" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="cpf">CPF *</label>
    </div>
    <p style="color: #d50000;" ng-show="myForm.cpf.$error.required && myForm.cpf.$dirty">Field Required</p>
    <p style="color: #d50000;" ng-show="myForm.cpf.$error.pattern">Only numbers</p>
    <p style="color: #d50000;" ng-show="myForm.cpf.$error.minlength">Min 11 Chars</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, and I think you can only disable the button or ignore the entered value by yourself. You can also check the $valid property in your controller and ignore the value... It is not so nice, but I found no other way.