# AngularJS validation on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have a register form that I wish to do validation on the moment a user clicks submit. This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<form ng-submit="RegistrationC.fireReg()" novalidate name="register">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="RegistrationC.first_name" required name="first_name">
                    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="register.first_name.$error" ng-show="submitted && register.first_name.$error">
                        <p ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="submitted=true">Register Now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is showing the validation message if a username is not typed in, but it still submits. What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

```
//init.js - RegistrationController
reg_list.fireReg = function () {
    var url = 'user/register';
    api.makeCall(reg_list, url)
        .then(function (response) {
            reg_list.response = response;
            console.warn(response);
            $location.path('/user/verify');
        })
        .catch(function (errorMessage) {
            console.log("got an error in initial processing", errorMessage);
            event.restoreButton();
        });
};
```

I know there's issues in this function, I will fix them at a later stage.

Comment: Can you add code of `RegistrationC.fireReg()` as well. Also why is `novalidation` at form?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, I don't want the HTML5 validation to fire. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs prevent form submission when input validation fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails)

Comment: novalidate is to prevent native browser validation and it is correct to use it

Comment: Essentially, you need to check `formname.$valid` inside your submit handler.

Comment: return false when you don't want to submit the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submit this form only if it is valid. `<whatever_form_name>.$valid`

```
<form ng-submit="register.$valid && RegistrationC.fireReg()" novalidate name="register">
```

Comment: Works if I put `register.$valid` first. Thanks!

Comment: @Bilal nope buddy `&&` condition will execute until it ends or finds false. In your answer first will go to the function and starting to execute the method then it will go for the check of validtion. how come this will stop form being submitted ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add checkpoint whether form is valid or not before submitting form

Try like this

```
<form ng-submit="register.$valid && RegistrationC.fireReg()" novalidate name="register">
```

Comment: Going to upvote this because it's correct, but question was answered first by @Bilal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable html5(or browser) validator, You have to remove 'required' attribute in your html code

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp