# Angular form with get & action, cancel submit on validation failure

Tags: angularjs

I have a form as follows:

```
<form name="ratiosReport" 
      novalidate 
      ng-submit="ratiosReport.$valid" 
      action="reports/ratios?fromDate={{vm.fromDate}}" 
      method="get">
```

If the `fromDate` hasn't been filled in, I'd like the form not to submit. How do I do this, is it possible?

Most use-cases are where the form doesn't have an action, and the ng-submit calls a method in the controller. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails), from which I took the `ng-submit` attribute, but it only works if calling a method, not preventing the `GET` submit to the `ACTION` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit), ng-submit **only prevents default actions**, i.e. posting to itself. So it's not an option. Looks like I need to remove the `action` attribute and build the url manually in a method in the controller, called by ng-submit (and effectively use `window.location.href = xxx`).