# How to do validation for dynamically generated textboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web application in `AngularJS`. I am generating some textboxes dynamically. I want to do validation for each of the generated textboxes.

Below is my html where I am generating textboxes.

```
<div ng-repeat="text in Textboxes">
    <input class="with-icon" type="text" name="{{text.name}}" required value="{{text.value}}"/>
</div>
```

Below is my JS code.

```
$scope.Textboxes = [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }, { name: 'name2', value: 'value2' }];
```

Whenever I click on submit button if I did not enter anything in text boxes then I want to make textboxes red.

Can it be done for dynamically generated textboxes?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269868/3551786)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `ng-model` instead of value
2. use a `ng-class` or `ng-style` to conditionally (hence check with
   the `text.value`) add some  style to make it red
3. use `$invalid` in the form to check whether all text field are
   validated with text entry or not, apply something (may be disabled)
   to submit button look and feel or in click event (prevent the action
   according to `$invalid` in the form)

Answer (score 1):

use `form` to validate the submit

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.Textboxes = [{ name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }, { name: 'name2', value: 'value2' }]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<form name="loginform">
 <div ng-repeat="text in Textboxes">
    <input class="with-icon" type="text" name="{{text.name}}" required value="{{text.value}}"/>
</div>
<button type="submit" >Login</button>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have developed plunker. I am looking for angular validation where i can make my input control red on form submit. https://plnkr.co/edit/B9H8wpNhBCVsH10fb1Tc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` to bind the values and then `ng-class` to set/remove **error** class that changes the border to red/black

I think This is what you're looking for

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/h3wVLOe0GcSM82d0ILIE?p=preview)