# AngularJS validation passes required empty fields

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-material

View for the form part looks like

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Add Attendee">
  <form ng-cloak class="form-horizontal" name="attendeeForm" ng-submit="save(ctrl.attendee) && attendeeForm.$valid" novalidate>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Enter Attendee</h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-4">First Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" ng-model="ctrl.attendee.firstName" ng-required="true" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-4">Last Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" ng-model="ctrl.attendee.lastName" ng-required="true" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-4">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" ng-model="ctrl.attendee.email" ng-required="true" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <span flex></span>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Attendee</button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

When I submit that form without required fields the form is passing validation and can be submited. When I will remove `novalidate` it works fine which has no sense based on an answer from [Angularjs prevent form submission when input validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails) which *states No need for controller checks.*

Any clue what is going on with it?

Comment: Change `ng-submit` to `attendeeForm.$valid && save(ctrl.attendee)`

Comment: @AlexK That did the job! I should to know that it can pass in my case `save` statement was before for became `true`