# angular form control required validator only works when their is form input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I've got a reactive form with nested formgroups with some form controls that have required validators.

It seems the validation only occurs when a user inputs values into the form.  If the
form is submitted with no user interaction, empty textboxes with a required validator show as valid.
Is this a normal behavior of angular forms? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Pete

html template:

```
<form [formGroup]="ticketMarkForm" (ngSubmit)="submitTicket()">
  ..
   <div formGroupName ="systemForm">
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Pipe Length (Ft):</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="number" required formControlName="pipeLength">
     </mat-form-field>
</div>
 ..
 <button type="submit" mat-stroked-button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

component typescript:

```
export class MtMarkFormComponent implements OnInit {
..
ticketMarkForm: FormGroup;
...
constructor(private checkService: MTMarkFormCheckService) { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
 //forms
 this.ticketMarkForm = new FormGroup({
  systemForm: new FormGroup({
    ...
   pipeDiameter: new FormControl(Validators.required),
   ...
  })
  });

}
submitTicket() {
   let pipeDiam:any=this.ticketMarkForm.get('systemForm').get('pipeDiameter');
   this.checkService.CheckRequiredValid(pipeDiam);
   }
}
```

Service to check form typescript:

```
export class MTMarkFormCheckService {
 CheckRequiredValid(fc: FormControl) {
        if (fc.invalid) {//if the control is left blank/untouched evaluates to valid.  I've also 
  tried to mark the control as dirty (fc.markAsDirty()) but same result
            alert("invalid");
         }
         else {
           alert("valid");
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is default Angular behavior. You have to define custom error state matcher like this.

```js
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class CustomErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null | undefined, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    if (control == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return control.invalid;
  }
}
```

ts :

```js
export class MtMarkFormComponent implements OnInit {
   :
  public esm = new CustomErrorStateMatcher();
   :
}
```

html :

```html
<input matInput type="number" required formControlName="pipeLength" [errorStateMatcher]="esm">
```

Comment: Thanks N.F.  I was able to apply your solution but I'm still getting the same behavior.  The user has to actually make a change to the value in the control and leave it blank to get an invalid flag for the control

Comment: Your Custom Error Matcher was the solution.  My problem was when I initialized the control.    I used:  pipeDiameter: new FormControl(Validators.required) should of used: pipeDiameter: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]).  I passed the validator as the first argument.  A working stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewa1kj?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts

Comment: the stackblitz above is based on this https://stackblitz.com/angular/brleoyyorkap?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not very clear but will try to explore

> empty textboxes with a required validator show as valid

I have tried to replicate the problem you have described in [this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-godmqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but I am getting different conclusions.

> **Empty textboxes with required validators will be return false for the valid property**

It is important to note that validations on the form will not show until the form is touched

In the demo I have commented out the line `// this.ticketMarkForm.markAllAsTouched()`. If this is uncommented, validations will show on the form

By default angular will call `(ngSubmit)='someFunction()'` (see [Angularjs prevent form submission when input validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails)) but the form status will be invalid.

If you try to submit the form in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-godmqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) You will notice that the console log shows false

Comment: Thanks Owen - I can see the form is always invalid no matter the input.  I'm going to try and build a stackblitz without the material form input and see what happens